# Problem regarding parts of speech

Tags: parts-of-speech

What would be the parts of speech of the bold words  :

(i) He goes to **London**  .

(ii) He knows  **better**  .

(iii) There is **lack** of knowledge  .

(iv) Look **before** you leap  .

**MY WORK :**

(i) Adjective  :  because it states the destination of verb *goes*  .

(ii) Adverb  :  because it decorates the *verb* , not the *noun* .

(iii) I have no idea regarding it  .... But I think it's adjective.

(iv) I think it's a conjunction  .

**Are my reasonings correct  ?**

Comment: ***London*** is a "proper **noun**", but the combination ***to London*** is **adverbial** (since it modifies the verb ***to go***). But I think you're asking about too many different things at once here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Aren't they related as I'm discussing a particular topic  ? That's why I've posted only a particular part...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

London: This one is easiest. It is the *name* of a city, so it is a proper noun.

Better: can be the comparative form of both the adjective good, and the adverb, well.  Here it modifies the verb "know" so it is an adverb

lack: a dictionary will show that this can function as either a verb or a noun in standard English. In this case is must be a noun.

before: This is the hardest one, before is usually either a prepostion of an adverb.  Here the prepositional use "before you leap" has been adapted to be a  conjunction meaning "in advance of the time when"

A dictionary will show parts of speech, and you can often compare the example sentences to see which most closely matches your examples

Comment: Shouldn't **London** be an **Adverb** in this special case?

Comment: No it is a proper noun. It names the city